# How much can a blue whale lift?

Tags: marine-biology

A simple question really. Given that the buoyancy in water kind of helps them under water, I'd specifically like to know, if there was, for Example, a boat, how heavy could it be that the blue whale could still push it out of the water.

Comment: This is less of a biology question and more of a textbook physics question.  Wikipedia suggests the max speed of a blue whale is [48 km/h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_whale#Swim_speed), and the largest whale weighed 173 metric tons.  If you assume collision with a boat is inelastic with force applied perpendicular to the surface of the water, you can calculate a max boat weight for an arbitrary vertical distance for the boat to be pushed (say, 0.5 m?).  Assume also that the whale stops swimming once contact is made.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as pointed out by @Dirigible this isn't really a biology question as defined for this site. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: I don’t think this is completely off-topic though, due to the fact that blue whales can use their muscles to swim and are maybe able to adjust their overall density by holding breath. So I guess this can be decomposed into more questions like: how much force or momentum can a blue whale generate while swimming? How much air can a blue whale hold in their respiratory system?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As I know about that and do research on this and find out some facts and figures I'll talk about both whale and krill. Due to the relative sizes of both the blue whale and krill, they can consume as many as 40 million krill, or 8,000 pounds (3,600 kg) of it daily.
These figures may change according to the age, weight, and other things of whale and krill

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then [edit] or delete your answer accordingly. ——— It is best to avoid answering poor and off-topic questions. It also isn't clear that this answers the question asked. In addition, answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. Please see the [help] for details about this site's goals. Thanks! 